# Why receiving TypeError Null?

Tags: javascript, null

This might be a silly question but being new to javascript I'm getting real frustrated.

I'm receiving `"TypeError: bajs is null" (line 2 in the js-file)`. What does it mean? What have I done wrong? Why doesn't it work?

This is the javascript:

```
var bajs = document.getElementById("canvas1");
bajs.addEventListener("click", hejhej, false);

function hejhej() {alert("it's working");}
```

This is the html:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500px" height="350px"></canvas>
```

Comment: element not found in html, `document.getElementById()`  returned null

Comment: You posted not the full code of html

Comment: When I try it in jsfiddle it works just fine on click...